# Header moves when I change the position of the div underneath / First Website

Tags: html, css

I just started building my own little website.
Already worked around some problems but now I'm stuck.

My header works perfectly (fixed) but the div underneath doesn't float beneath it.
And when I'm giving the `div(#box)` a margin top the header also moves.
My box is just a visualization for me to see that something is going on.
Position relative or absolute, I'm not quite sure what the difference is, just puts the div in the foreground.

Additionally, when I look at the page in Safari, my header has a height of 0.

- Shouldn't it scale with the content?
- How do I separate these two things?

```css
body, html{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;

}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    
    position: fixed;

    padding-top: 20px;
}




nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 10%;
    list-style: none;

}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 35px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

nav a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 15px;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.250);
}



#marclogo {
    display: block;   
    margin: auto;
    width: 30%;
}





#photo:after{
    content: 'photo';
}
#photo:hover:after{
    content: 'video';
}
#music:after{
    content: 'music';
}
#music:hover:after{
    content: 'commercial';
}
#video:after{
    content: 'video';
}
#video:hover:after{
    content: 'photo';
}
#commercial:after{
    content: 'commercial';
}
#commercial:hover:after{
    content: 'music';
}






#box {
   
    height: 2000px;
    background: #33ee5b;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Schroellkamp</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:900|Open+Sans:300" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>


<body>

    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a id="photo" href="#"></a></li>
                    <li><a id="music" href="#"></a></li>
                    <li><a id="video" href="#"></a></li>
                    <li><a id="commercial" href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <img id="marclogo" src="img/MarcS.png" alt="logo">
        </div>
    </header>

    



    <div id="box"></div>







    <footer>
    </footer>


</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `top:0;` and `background:#fff;` to `header` and `margin-top` to `#box` also remove `position:fixed;` from `.container`.
Here is the updated fiddle:

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: #fff;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 10%;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 35px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

nav a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.250);
}

#marclogo {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 30%;
}

#photo:after {
  content: 'photo';
}

#photo:hover:after {
  content: 'video';
}

#music:after {
  content: 'music';
}

#music:hover:after {
  content: 'commercial';
}

#video:after {
  content: 'video';
}

#video:hover:after {
  content: 'photo';
}

#commercial:after {
  content: 'commercial';
}

#commercial:hover:after {
  content: 'music';
}

#box {
  height: 2000px;
  background: #33ee5b;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Schroellkamp</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:900|Open+Sans:300" rel="stylesheet">
</head>


<body>

  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a id="photo" href="#"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a id="music" href="#"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a id="video" href="#"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a id="commercial" href="#"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <img id="marclogo" src="img/MarcS.png" alt="logo">
    </div>
  </header>

  <div id="box"></div <footer>
  </footer>


</body>


</html>
```